# if else condition in smarty .tpl for nth-child list/div

Tags: php, css, smarty

I'm working with Smarty. I want to add an `if else` condition in my `.tpl` file for nth-child li/div classes.

I have two image sizes. I want to use the 600px image in the first `li`, the 400px image in the 2nd and 3rd, and again the 600px image in the 4th `li` and so on.

Currently I'm using the CSS3 `nth-child` selector and using scaled 400px images. But the load time is bad. I want to use smaller images where required.

I guess its very complex. Is it?

Here is my code:

```
<img src="{$purl}/thumbs/{$posts[i].pic}" alt="{$posts[i].story|stripslashes}" />
```

and it exists in loop `{section name=i loop=$posts} {include file="posts.tpl"} {/section}` inside `posts.tpl`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[cycle](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.cycle.tpl) will be helpfull.

Let's assume that you have array with path to pictures stored in two fields: `image-600` and `image-400`:

```
{foreach from=$images item=image}
    {capture assign=currentKey}image-{cycle values='600,400,400'}{/capture}
    <li><img src="{$image[$currentKey]}" alt="{$image.title}" /></li>
{/foreach}
```

in your case it will probably look like this:

```
{section name=i loop=$posts}
   {capture assign=thumbSize}{cycle values='big,small,small'}{/capture}
   <img src="{$purl}/thumbs/{if $thumbSize eq 'big'}{$posts[i].pic}{else}s-{$r[i].pic}{/if}" alt="{$posts[i].story|stripslashes}" />
{/section}
```

Comment: please check the above code. thanks for helping. I've studied cycle and it seems the correct method.

Comment: my image tags are  `{$purl}/thumbs/s-{$r[i].pic}` for 400px and `{$purl}/thumbs/{$posts[i].pic}` for 600px hope it will help you to understand